# Cors Blocks Request with status 403 on Nginx

Tags: nginx, cors, http-status-code-403

I am facing a strange issue with running CORS on Nginx, CORS is working fine for everything but one scenario when the Server responds with a 403 http response.

Basically when I login with correct credentials the cors request works fine , however when I provide wrong credentials for login the server(backend) responds with a 403 status and I get the following error

`"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://mydomain.com/v1/login"
login
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mydomain.com/v1/login. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

If the credentials are correct I don't get this error and everything works perfectly.

I have done the configuration for enabling CORS and it seems to be working fine for everything else.

Following are the Request Headers

**Request Headers**

    `User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
    Referer:http://abc.mydomain.com/
    Pragma: no-cache
    Origin: http://abc.mydomain.com
    Host:   www.mydomain.com
    Content-Type:   application/json;charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 74
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control:  no-cache
    Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, /`

**Response Headers**

    `Server: nginx/1.4.1
    Date:   Tue, 10 Jun 2014 05:28:30 GMT
    Content-Type:   application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 76
    Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: maybe pasting request and response headers will help to answer your question

Comment: @Marcel I have updated the post with Request and Response Headers

Comment: It does not look like a problem, RESTFUL API means that if you input wrong credentials it would responds with 403, as it is supposed to.

Comment: @Marcel absolutely , problem is that when Server responds with a 403 , I start getting a CORS error on the firebug console.

Comment: there is no CORS related header in headers pasted.

Answer (score 5):

An option for nginx(>=1.75) is to specify `always` parameter in [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) :

> If the always parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be
>   added regardless of the response code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using `add_header` directive to add CORS headers in the nginx configuration.

Nginx modules reference states about `add_header`:

> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307.

To fix problem you could use [`ngx_headers_more`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#Installation) module to set CORS headers also to error responses.

```
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin';

more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Cookie';
```